# T-SQL multiple datetime diff on one line

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server (T-SQL), and I have two tables:

`tblTrial`:

```
TrialID (PK) int
TrialDate
...
```

`tblLaps`:

```
LapID (PK) int
TrialID (FK) int
LapNumber int
LapStart smalldatetime
...
```

For `TrialID = 1`, there are four `Lap` rows:

```
LapID  TrialID   LapNumber    LapStart
  1       1          1         t1 (some smalldatetime value)
  2       1          2         t2
  3       1          3         t3
  4       1          4         t4
```

I want to display the SQL so that for each Trial, only one row is displayed, and it has the time differences.

For example, a row for `TrialID = 1` might look like:

```
Trial#   1stLap   2ndLap   3rdLap
---------------------------------
   1       3min     4min     5min
```

where 1stLap is time difference t2-t1, 2ndLap is t3-t2, 3rdLap is t4-t3.

How do I make everything go on one line in a SQL statement?

Thanks

Comment: Make use of stored procedure and do calculation in that and return data as one line. Thanks!!

Comment: I think you want Pivot, check this out http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
        t.TrialID
      , datediff(minute, max(case when LapNumber = 1 then LapStart end) , max(case when LapNumber = 2 then LapStart end) ) lap1_2
      , datediff(minute, max(case when LapNumber = 2 then LapStart end) , max(case when LapNumber = 3 then LapStart end) ) lap2_3
      , datediff(minute, max(case when LapNumber = 3 then LapStart end) , max(case when LapNumber = 4 then LapStart end) ) lap3_4
from tblTrial as t
inner join tblLaps as l on t.TrialID = l.TrialID
group by
        t.TrialID
```

see [this sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bda6/6)

Answer (score 1):

For time difference in minutes, you could do like this:

```
with laps as  -- First CTE table to join every lap with the next lap to get end time
(
select TrialID,t1.LapID, datediff(mi,t1.LapStart, t2.LapStart ) as Lap
from tblLaps t1
join tblLaps t2
on   t1.LapID = t2.LapID - 1  and t1.TrialID = t2.TrialID
)
select TrialID, 
       max(case t1.LapID when 1 then Lap else null end) as [1stLap],
       max(case t1.LapID when 2 then Lap else null end) as [2ndLap],
       max(case t1.LapID when 3 then Lap else null end) as [3rdLap],
from   laps
group  by TrialID
```

If you want differ by seconds, use `datediff(ss,startdate , enddate )`, here's the [datediff document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).